# Word capture failing wrong on unicode, how to fix for 5.10

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I have this regular expresion.

```
my ( $word ) = $_ =~ /(\w{2,})/xms;
```

it fails to capture a word that has unicode properly. I was able to fix it doing

```
my ( $word ) = $_ =~ /(\w{2,})/uxms;
```

but the `/u` feature is only available in 5.14. Is there anyway I can make the words match in 5.10?

The full code is here: [Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Test::PodSpelling](https://metacpan.org/source/XENO/Dist-Zilla-Plugin-Test-PodSpelling-2.002006/lib/Dist/Zilla/Plugin/Test/PodSpelling.pm#L51)

adding some carps (before and after regex)

```
Simões at /home/ccushing/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.2/lib/site_perl/5.16.2/x86_64-linux/Class/MOP/Method/Wrapped.pm line 162.
Sim at /home/ccushing/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.2/lib/site_perl/5.16.2/x86_64-linux/Class/MOP/Method/Wrapped.pm line 162.
```

also noting  that simply adding `use 5.014` to the top of the file fixes the problem. adding `utf8::upgrade( $_ )` before the regex did not fix the problem.

Comment: Afaik `\w` should match unicode characters in 5.10. Make sure that your string is properly encoded and that Perl is aware of that it is in unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\p{Word}` instead of `\w`. `\w` might or might not have unicode semantics (depending on some complex rules), but `\p` always does.

Answer (score 1):

`use feature qw( unicode_strings );` will do the trick in some version. `utf8::upgrade($_);` before the match will do the trick in all versions.

Test:

```
use open ':std', ':utf8';
$_ = "Sim\xF5es";
print $_ =~ /(\w{2,})/xms, "\n";
utf8::upgrade($_);
print $_ =~ /(\w{2,})/xms, "\n";
```

Output:

```
Sim
Simões
```

Comment: It most definitely does, as you can see in the test I've added in an update.

Comment: I don't know, it didn't work within my code block when I tried to add it last night.

Comment: I can't tell you why unless you show me a demonstration of the problem.